# F# - Take the right half of a string

Tags: f#

I'm trying to write a function that takes the right half of the string operand:

```
let f(k:'string)= k.[..(k.Length/2)]
```

Here's the error message:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.2.32702+c4012a063 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

/home/runner/project/Program.fs(1,19): error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved. [/home/runner/project/project.fsproj]

Build FAILED.

/home/runner/project/Program.fs(1,19): error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved. [/home/runner/project/project.fsproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.74
```

Why is this error caused, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is 100% equivalent to this:

```
let f (k:'a)= k.[..(k.Length/2)]
```

and to this:

```
let f (k:'whatevs)= k.[..(k.Length/2)]
```

and to this:

```
let f (k:'some_generic_type)= k.[..(k.Length/2)]
```

A single quote (aka "tick") in front of an identifier is used in F# to denote a type variable (aka "generic type"). So while `string` is a type of text strings, `'string` is a completely different thing - it's a type variable, which you happened to name "string" for some reason. You could have chosen any other name, the compiler doesn't really care (see my examples above), but you chose "string". "So what," - thinks the compiler - "that's your prerogative."

And since the type is completely generic, the compiler doesn't know which methods it may have - that is, whether it has an indexer or a property `Length`. So it complains: "*Lookup on object of indeterminate type ...*"

To tell the compiler that the type in question is, indeed, `string`, just remove the tick:

```
let f (k:string)= k.[..(k.Length/2)]
```